# Safari-Like ScrollBars in ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have an application written in WPF with a ScrollViewer controlling a Canvas. This ScrollViewer can pan and zoom using the mouse. What I want to do is have the same types of ScrollBars that Safari has on both MacOS and iOS. Below is an example. Any help on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Safari ScrollBar on iOS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retemplate the scrollbar element

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx

You can use expression blend to help you styling any WPF element

Here an example

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd334546